# iOS: Use of undeclared identifiers with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am very new to iOS, but I am on the verge of completing my app if I can get this error to go away. I'm experienced in C and C++, but objective-c has been rather confusing to me in the way in which things are done.

Header File:

```
@interface ThirdTableViewController : UITableViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

-(id) init;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *csvFileNames;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *csvFilePaths;
- (IBAction)refreshTableButton:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sendEmailButton:(id)sender;
void refreshTable();

@end
```

Implementation File:

```
void refreshTable(){
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSArray *documentArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    NSArray *csvFiles = [documentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [evaluatedObject hasSuffix:@".csv"];
    }]];

    _csvFileNames = csvFiles;

    for (NSString *fileName in csvFiles) {
        [_csvFilePaths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
    }

    //NSLog(@"files array %@", _fileNamesArray);
    //NSLog(@"files array %@", _filePathsArray);
}
```

I'm getting the errors where my two NSMutableArrays declared in the .h file are used in the .m file. These are the specific lines:

```
_csvFileNames = csvFiles;

[_csvFilePaths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
```

These are the specific errors: Use of undeclared identifier '_csvFileNames', Use of undeclared identifier '_csvFilePaths'

In C++ if we are to implement a class function we do something like class::myfunction(parameters...). I assume my issue is somewhere along these lines.

Comment: Declare then as NSString - how does the error (not) change? Use this to refine the title and make it more accurate to the problem.

Comment: Update your question with the actual and complete error messages.

Comment: I will do it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `refreshTable` function. It's a function, not an instance method. Such a function has no access to any instance methods or variable of the class.

In the .h, change:

```
void refreshTable();
```

to:

```
- (void)refreshTable;
```

Update the .m:

```
void refreshTable(){
```

to:

```
- (void)refreshTable {
```

Then where ever you call it, change:

```
refreshTable();
```

to:

```
[self refreshTable];
```

Once you do that you will have other problems. You are attempting to assign an `NSArray` to a variable of type `NSMutableArray`. Change this code:

```
NSArray *csvFiles = [documentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject hasSuffix:@".csv"];
}]];

_csvFileNames = csvFiles;

for (NSString *fileName in csvFiles) {
    [_csvFilePaths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
}
```

to:

```
NSArray *csvFiles = [documentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject hasSuffix:@".csv"];
}]];

_csvFileNames = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *fileName in csvFiles) {
    [_csvFilePaths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
}
```

Better yet, use your properties:

```
self.csvFileNames = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *fileName in csvFiles) {
    [self.csvFilePaths addObject:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. That makes much more sense now.

Answer (score -1):

In your refreshTable method, you declared csvFiles as NSArray and tried to assign it to _csvFileNames which is NSMutableArray.

You can't assign an variable NSArray to a NSMutableArray variable.

Comment: This is a valid problem but the OP hasn't hit it yet due to the actual cause of the error in the question. Once the current issue is resolved, this issue will need to be fixed next. FYI - I didn't down vote.

Comment: I appreciate the reply. I upvoted you to hopefully get rid of whoever downvoted